# Ruby, Paperclip, Formtastic, ActiveAdmin and images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, activeadmin, formtastic

How do I create a form in Paperclip, ActiveAdmin, and Formtastic? The image is not part of the model, but part of a sub-model.

I tried:

```
form :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
   f.inputs "Ticket Info" do
      ...
      f.input :image1.photo
      f.input :image2.photo
```

But it gave an error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'photo' for :image1:Symbol):`.

Here is the Ticket model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ... :image1_id, :image2_id
...
  belongs_to :image1, class_name: "TicketImage"
  belongs_to :image2, class_name: "TicketImage"
```

Here is the TicketImage model:

```
class TicketImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :file, :photo
  has_one :ticket
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
end
```

---

I also tried `f.input :image1` but it just gave me an empty select box.

---

I also tried `f.input :image1, :as => :file`, but it gave me this error after I selected a file and clicked submit:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Admin::TicketsController#update
TicketImage(#89768376) expected, got ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile(#29533068)
```

---

I also tried

```
  f.semantic_fields_for :image1 do |image|   
        image.input :photo, :as => :file, :name => "Image1"
  end
  f.semantic_fields_for :image2 do |image|   
        image.input :photo, :as => :file, :name => "Image2"
  end
```

but it only gave one file select button labeled Photo, and after I submitted, gave this error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Admin::TicketsController#update
TicketImage(#86546820) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#20656416)
```

---

I also tried this: Added:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Ticket do
    ...
    f.input :photo, :as => :file, :for => :image1, :name => "Image 1"

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ... :image1_id, :image2_id, :image1_attributes, ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :image1, :image2, :allow_destroy => true


class TicketImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :file, :photo, :photo_file_name, :photo_content_type, :photo_file_size, :photo_updated_at
```

And the file upload box appears and accepts an upload, but in the log, it says:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: photo
```

---

I also tried this, which works with ONE upload field, but when both are put in the form, NEITHER are displayed! There are no errors in the server log either:

```
  f.semantic_fields_for :image1 do |image|
    image.input :photo, :as => :file, :name => "Image1", :hint => image.object.nil? ? "No Image" : f.template.image_tag(image.object.photo.url(:thumb))
  end
  # f.semantic_fields_for :image2 do |image|   
    # image.input :photo, :as => :file, :name => "Image2", :hint => image.object.nil? ? "No Image" : f.template.image_tag(image.object.photo.url(:thumb))
  # end
```

---

I also tried this, which seems to works all the way and save images, except it allows you to create one-to-many association with the image1 field, which is only a single entry! I haven't tried adding two images to image1, but I expect it to crash.

```
  f.has_many :image1  do |p|
    p.input :photo, :as => :file, :label => "Image 1", :hint => p.template.image_tag(p.object.photo.url(:thumb)) 
    p.input :_destroy, :as=>:boolean, :required => false, :label => 'Remove image'
  end
  f.has_many :image2  do |p|
    p.input :photo, :as => :file, :label => "Image 2", :hint => p.template.image_tag(p.object.photo.url(:thumb)) 
    p.input :_destroy, :as=>:boolean, :required => false, :label => 'Remove image'
  end
```

---

This works the best, but hints don't work!

```
  f.inputs :photo, :as => :file, :for => :image1, :name => "Image 1", :hint => "A Hint"
  f.inputs :photo, :as => :file, :for => :image2, :name => "Image 2", :hint => "A Hint"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested forms are also supported by Formtastic:

```
form :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  f.input :number
  f.semantic_fields_for :image1 do |image|   
    image.input :photo, :name => "Image1"
  f.semantic_fields_for :image2 do |image|   
    image.input :photo, :name => "Image2"
```

Comment: I tried that, but got this error: `TicketImage(#83482896) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#20656416)`. Plus, only one Photo field showed up. I also had to add `end` after each do block.

Comment: Naa, Rails is backwards. All my other relationships are belongs_to (which really means has_one). I tried changing it to has_one, and viewing the form, and it crashed with the error: Unknown column 'ticket_images.ticket_id'.

Comment: Try building the association before fields_for (or in the fields_for declaration). `ticket.image1.build` `ticket.image2.build`. Also, the nested attribute attr_accessible should be photo_attributes on the ticket model.